# Why are my changes not pushed in github actions?

Tags: github-actions

I have the following script to increment the version number in package.json and push it:

```
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        persist-credentials: false
        fetch-depth: 0

    - name: Environment
      run: | 
        echo "Environment: $ENVIRONMENT"

    - name: Increase version and tag
      run: | 
        git config --global user.name "${GITHUB_ACTOR}"
        git config --global user.email "${GITHUB_ACTOR}@users.noreply.github.com"
        npm version patch -m "[RELEASE] %s" --tag-version-prefix="release/v"
        git push "https://${GITHUB_ACTOR}:${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}@github.com/${{ github.repository }}" --tags
```

The output of this is

```
release/v1.0.1
Everything up-to-date
```

So it seems the `npm version patch` command is run successfully but the changes are not pushed. I think there is no commit command needed. If I try it locally it works fine.

Comment: Can you try again by adding `clean: false` to the checkout action?

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't change anything.